# Prove that $2^n = O(n!)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Do I have to use induction to prove this? I tried this:

> Basis Step
>
> $n = 1$
>
> $2^1 = O(1!)$
>
> $2 = O(1)$

This doesn't work and neither does 0.

Comment: It might be helpful to prove that $2^n < n!$ for $n\geq 4$..

Comment: What is a case where these two are actually equal?

Comment: @Jess Big-O notation is an upper bound, so equality is not really necessary.

Comment: For $n=1,2,3$ respectively, $2^n$ is $2,4,8$, while $n!$ is $1,2,6$. They are never equal, but it isn't needed. The result still holds, and follows directly from my first comment.

Comment: @Jess $2 = O(1)$ is true, so that is not a problem.  However, it's generally poor form to prove by $f(n) = O(g(n))$ by individually proving $f(1) = O(g(1)), f(2) = O(g(2)), f(3) = O(g(3)),$ etc.  The latter statements are true in a trivial sense by adjusting the implied constant for each $n$, whereas $f(n) = O(g(n))$ demands a uniform constant across all $n$.

Comment: @Jess Try proving the inequality $2^n \le 2\cdot n!$ for all $n\ge 1$.  The whole point of $O$ notation is that you get to choose the constant to be as high as you want, to make the proof go through easier (but then you have to stick with it for all values of $n$).

Answer (score 1):

Prove $2^n=O(n!)$

We must show

$\exists( M,x_0 \in \mathbb{R}) \text{ such that } \forall (n > x_0) (2^n \leq M n!) $

This is saying $Mn!$ is greater than or equal to $2^n$ for some real number M, for every $n$ greater than some other real number $x_0$.

Following the suggestion by Nicholas Stull in the comments above and your own suggestion of using induction, we can prove this for $M=1$ and $x_0 = 4$.

Basis : $2^4 = 16 < 24 = 4!$

Suppose it works for $k$, ie assume $2^k < k!$ for some $k$, and show it works for $k+1$

$2^{k+1} = 2(2^k) < (k+1)(2^k) < (k+1)k! = (k+1)!$